# Quality of OData in Mono for Android

Tags: wcf, mono, xamarin.android, wcf-client, wcf-data-services-client

I am looking to create some cross platform libraries. One of the most important things for me for my mobile platforms is to access web services. After doing quite a bit of reading, it seems that the best solution would be to write against DataServiceContext (wcf-data-services-client).

Before I write my cross platform library and start my mono for android trial, I wanted to know if anyone has any experience with this library on Android? Does anyone have any experience using any of the WCF client libraries on Mono for Android? Any information or personal experiences on the subject would be helpful.

Thank you.